# Offline Processing of POST Request

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, offline

I am developing an Application where I am submitting POST Requests to a .NET Web Service.

Current implementation is to process the request instantly and give response. In actual deployment, there will be huge amount of data that needs to be processed and thus the request must be processed offline.

What are the strategies that can have the task accomplished

Should I implement a Windows Service, or a scheduled task that invokes an application to perform the desired task.

Comment: If you're doing this as a web service, you need to have some kind of immediate response, even if it's just verifying that the request was successfully submitted.  After that, the question of whether or not you'd want a service constantly running to monitor the request queue or periodically executed to work its way through it should be determined by how quickly you need responses and whether there's any advantage to processing requests in bulk.

Comment: @ngroot: For the application, it is preferred that the requests are not processed in bulk. In fact, it's desirable that exactly one request is processed at a time. Another issue is, user needs to be informed by email when processing is done. Hence, there will be few configuration informations that may later need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have so much data it cannot be processed in real-time, I would probably setup the service to do the following:

ProcessRecordViaPost

1. Create new record in "Queue" database with UniqueID, and all other info to be processed
2. Return UniqueID to client immediatly

ReadRecordViaGet

1. Check queue, if processed return data if not return status code (number of items in queue before it?)

I would also have a windows service that continually grabs the oldest item from the Queue, and processes it and moves on to the next oldest.

Comment: Since the service will continually grab data, it's not wise to keep the requests on a database right? So, is it best to use MSMQ for storing the requests.

Comment: If they are only going to be processed and deleted, then yeah, a database would be overkill. However, since you aren't passing data back immediatly, how will your web service return data when the user finally comes back for it? It seems like you need to store the queue at least until the user makes the second request, no?

Comment: Bross: There will not be any second request. The user will be notified through email.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a good case for MSMQ.  Your webservice can fill the queue with incoming data, and another process can read those messages and perform the necessary processing.

Here's a good overview of MSMQ:

http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article77.aspx